# How to read a file and wrap the text at 80 characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a small Python beginner project where I take a text document and add a new line to it every 80 characters without breaking words.  I also want to keep any new lines between paragraphs.  My understanding of Python is beginner at best. right now I have:

```
import textwrap

text_file = open('txt_file_name.txt', 'r')
print(textwrap.wrap(text_file, 80))
text_file.close()
```

I'm starting to think `textwrap` might now be the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files are generally opened and referenced using a `with` block, which handles closing the file handle automatically, even if an exception is raised.

You may also want to use `textwrap.fill()`, which appends a newline to each processed paragraph.

```
import textwrap

with open('txt_file_name.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(textwrap.fill(line, width=80))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly!  Your solution worked for me and your short explanations are informative.